# How to compile scala 2.11.2 with bigger tupes?

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-2.11, scala-compiler

I tried to build scala 2.11.2 with bigger tuples (arity over 22) by following this guide: 
http://blog.rogach.org/2013/02/scala-tuplicity-comes-to-210.html

I have no previous experience with building the scala library & compiler and the ant build tool, so I just tried to run the script on a fresh git clone of tag v2.11.2 and hoped it will work. It didn't.

I got an error on line `ant replacelocker`:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "replacelocker" does not exist in the project "sabbus".
```

Seems like the way scala 2.11 is built has changed. I was not able to find any specific info on how to replace the `ant replacelocker` line.

Is it possible to build scala 2.11.2 with bigger tuples like it is possible for 2.9 and 2.10? What has to be done differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile scala with 64-arity tuples using this script, though it's probably not the optimal way (first compilation fails on missing classes above 22-arity, second pass finishes OK):

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

ARITY=64

#mv scala scala-`date +%y%m%d-%H%M%S`
#git clone https://github.com/scala/scala.git
#cp -R scala-fresh scala
#cd scala
git checkout -b 2.11.2-local tags/v2.11.2
export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx7G -Xss25M -Xms4G -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
#VERS="-Dbuild.release=true -Dversion.number=2.11.2-local -Dmaven.version.number=2.11.2-local"
VERS="-Dbuild.release=true"
sed -i "s/\(val MaxTupleArity, .*\) 22/\1 $ARITY/" src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Definitions.scala
ant build $VERS
sed -i "s/22/$ARITY/" src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala
sed -i "s/\(MAX_ARITY .*\) 22/\1 $ARITY/" src/build/genprod.scala
sed -i 's/import scala.language.postfixOps//' src/build/genprod.scala
echo 'genprod.main(Array("src/library/scala/"))' >> src/build/genprod.scala
scala src/build/genprod.scala
ant build $VERS
```